# How to make rawTransaction? and Can I get some guide or reference about offchain sign?

Tags: polkadot-js, parachain, transactions, api, astar

[Question]

1. How can I make raw-transaction(unsigned-transaction) with essential parameter(fromAddress, toAddress, value, nonce, fee etc)? I want to know low-level algorithm.
2. What kind of Cryptography is used on Polkadot? I think it use sr25519, isn't it?
3. In below code log, which data on trsfRawTx is used for sign? And Which Cryptography-function(js) can I use?
4. I'm using send() function for broadcasting signedTx. Is there other function to broadcast signTx by parameter?
5. For signing, I'm using mnemonic & keyring, and I can get address & public-key from keyring. How can I get private-key? If it can, How Can I sign by private-key?

[Environment]
I'm developing a nodejs program on shibuya testnet.

[Goal]

1. I want to make raw-transaction(unsigned-transaction) for tranferring & staking token.
2. I want to sign raw-transaction and get signed-transaction on offchain-environment.
3. I want to broadcast signed-transaction to node(public-endpoint).

[Attempt]

- I tried to make sampleTransfer SampleCode using provided sample-example.
- Just using provided api, have no problem, but I have to migrate on my system.

```
const sampleTransfer = async () => {

    // Create a new instance of the api
    const provider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.shibuya.astar.network');
    const api = new ApiPromise(options({ provider }));

    const testAcnt1 = 'VxJhKGJ7wsVwZvaikWQzhexb9VawgFUtBuXNAmDAhBBVi4U';
    const testAcnt2 = '5HBSNV13JH7LuEtJUBNuKgcaPgNaXGBZhCknUWrKmD9p8vhA';

    await api.isReady;

    console.log('===== STEP1-RawTx-Start =====');
    const trsfRawTx = api.tx.balances.transfer(testAcnt1, BigInt(200000000000000000));
    console.log(trsfRawTx);
    // Submittable { initialU8aLength: undefined, registry: TypeRegistry {} }
    console.log('===== ===== =====');
    console.log(`${trsfRawTx}`);
    // {"signature":{"signer":{"id":"VwJHxi1vTNdnJ2KXfQ7tWL8ERiUGv9bwhmf5RDWKGySQmsy"},"signature":{"ed25519":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"era":{"immortalEra":"0x00"},"nonce":0,"tip":0},"method":{"callIndex":"0x1f00","args":{"dest":{"id":"VxJhKGJ7wsVwZvaikWQzhexb9VawgFUtBuXNAmDAhBBVi4U"},"value":"0x000000000000000002c68af0bb140000"}}}
    console.log('===== STEP1-RawTx-End =====');

    console.log('===== STEP2-SignRawTx-Start =====');
    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
    const testAcnt2Mnemonic = '...MNEMONIC...';
    const testAcnt2Key = keyring.addFromUri(testAcnt2Mnemonic);
    console.log(`testAcnt2Key : ${testAcnt2Key.address}`);
    // testAcnt2Key : 5HBSNV13JH7LuEtJUBNuKgcaPgNaXGBZhCknUWrKmD9p8vhA
    console.log('===== ===== =====');
    const signedTx = await trsfRawTx.signAsync(testAcnt2Key);
    console.log(signedTx);
    // Submittable { initialU8aLength: undefined, registry: TypeRegistry {} }
    console.log('===== ===== =====');
    console.log(`signedTx : ${signedTx}`);
    // signedTx : {"signature":{"signer":{"id":"b42omy85WkT84v8xUq2MLmrUj5hVUtJiQFviE4Bda9mjH2V"},"signature":{"sr25519":"0x424a05493a61a47b6952b3357bcc08e2d210b566be82ec7fe506840483a9831800c3d355eb4302f676cbeb7d4252602c1d99ddda58e8c292171b72094ed2ac86"},"era":{"mortalEra":"0xe400"},"nonce":6,"tip":0},"method":{"callIndex":"0x1f00","args":{"dest":{"id":"VxJhKGJ7wsVwZvaikWQzhexb9VawgFUtBuXNAmDAhBBVi4U"},"value":"0x000000000000000002c68af0bb140000"}}}
    console.log('===== STEP2-SignRawTx-End =====');

    console.log('===== STEP3-SendSignedTx-Start =====');
    const txhash = await signedTx.send();
    console.log(txhash);
    /*Type(32) [Uint8Array] [
        200,
        2,
        33,
        72,
        119,
        185,
        239,
        160,
        204,
        131,
        232,
        7,
        240,
        121,
        215,
        203,
        71,
        157,
        105,
        98,
        100,
        46,
        130,
        158,
        88,
        129,
        19,
        225,
        222,
        218,
        10,
        203,
        registry: TypeRegistry {},
        initialU8aLength: 32
      ]*/
    console.log('===== ===== =====');
    console.log(`txhash : ${txhash}`);
    // txhash : 0xc802214877b9efa0cc83e807f079d7cb479d6962642e829e588113e1deda0acb
    console.log('===== STEP3-SendSignedTx-End =====');
}

sampleTransfer().catch(console.error).finally(() => process.exit());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In order to make an unsigned transaction you can create an object with the required chain metadata and payload information:

```
// create unsigned transaction payload
const unsigned = {
          specVersion: specVersion,
          transactionVersion: transactionVersion,
          address: address,
          blockHash: blockHash,
          blockNumber: blockNumber,
          era: api.registry.createType('ExtrinsicEra', {
            current: blockNumber,
            period: 64,
          }),
          genesisHash: genesisHash,
          method: api.tx.balances.transfer(testAcnt1, BigInt(200000000000000000)).method.toHex(),
          nonce: accountNonce,
          signedExtensions: [
            'CheckNonZeroSender',
            'CheckSpecVersion',
            'CheckTxVersion',
            'CheckGenesis',
            'CheckMortality',
            'CheckNonce',
            'CheckWeight',
            'ChargeTransactionPayment',
          ],
          tip: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000',
          version: 4,
      };

// create an extrinsic payload to sign and get the signature
    const extrinsicPayload = this.registry.createType('ExtrinsicPayload', unsigned, {
      version: unsigned.version
    })

// get signature by passing your account keypair to the sign method on the extrinsic payload
const signature = extrinsicPayload.sign(keypair);

// create extrinsic from the unsigned payload
const extrinsic = registry.createType(
        'Extrinsic',
        { method: unsigned.method },
        { version: unsigned.version }
    );

// with the received signature from the sign method on the ExtrinsicPayload,
    extrinsic.addSignature(unsigned.address, signature, unsigned);

// save the hex of the signed extrinsic to later send to the public node
const hex = extrinsic.toHex();
```

2. Yes, Polkadot uses Schnorrkel/Ristretto x25519 ("sr25519") as its key derivation and signing algorithm. You can find more information on the hashing algorithm and how keypairs/signing are implemented here https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-cryptography.
3. The private key of the account is used to sign the tx. The function you can use is `tx.sign(keypair)` passing in a keypair created using the keyring.
4. In addition to the signAsync method which you’ve used in your example, the SubmittableExtrinsic has a `send` as well as `signAndSend` which accepts the from account, additional signer options such as the `signer`, and a status callback which can be used to check the status of the tx and its associated events. More on submitting transactions here: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/extension/cookbook#sign-and-send-a-transaction
5. PolkadotJS doesn’t currently support accessing KeyPair private keys. The polkadot-js extension does allow you to save the private key on account creation in its user interface but there is no programmatic way to access the private key on the keyring.